# How to create a non-incognito window from an incognito window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a Chrome extension that the user can enable for incognito, which works as intended. Upon button press, I'm trying to force a specific url to NOT open incognito, even when initiated from within an incognito window.

```
chrome.windows.create({ 'url': 'https://www.google.com', 'incognito': false });
```

But it only creates another incognito window.

Is it possible to create a non-incognito window and/or tab from within an incognito window?

Comment: Kind of defeats the purpose of the user being able to open in "incognito" in the first place. FWIW If I were to visit your site and it did that I would probably block your site.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss the question is about an extension, not a site

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss This is an internal tool for a company. Your concern is valid for a consumer product, but this is a specific usecase.

Comment: "Upon button press" - Where is this button? An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be better than a prose description of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### No, it is not possible

Chrome's extension API deliberately prevents you from creating a non-incognito window or tab from within an incognito window.

The intention of incognito mode is to ensure that the rest of the browsing history and data are *not* accessible. Part of this is is making sure that you can't open such non-incognito tabs or windows.